# Hybrid mobile frameworks that does not use NPM

Tags: open-source, framework, programming, mobile

I'm looking for a hybrid mobile framework (like cordova, ionic, etc), which does not use [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)), the default [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). I've had numerous issues with NPM over the years, and [this is the latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727130/npm-warn-deprecated-minimatch2-0-10-but-i-have-3-10-7). I developed a hatred for NodeJS and especially NPM, I worked in many languages over the years and many package managers and I have never had any problems, except when using Node and NPM.

Requirements are:

- A hybrid mobile framework that doesn't use NPM as its package manager, and hopefully doesn't rely on NodeJS.
- Open source, no commercial restrictions
- Can be deployed on Android and IOS
- Have native capabilities (Like access to GPS).
- Doesn't rely on Cordova
- Actively developed and hopefully has a decent community, either on StackOverflow or in forums, and decent documentation.

It doesn't have to be HTML/CSS/JS, I know many programming languages, pretty much any language is fine as long as it's not VB.net/C# and as long as I can publish cross platform apps. And I'm not interested in game engines such as Corona.

Comment: Does your app run standalone, offline? Or does it require an internet connection?

Comment: @BasilBourque it requires internet connection

Comment: Just an idea, not sure if it fits your needs: [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) and its extension, [Vaadin TouchKit](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/touchkit). Vaadin is an open-source framework for developing desktop-style web apps that run in pure Java on the server-side while automagically rendering in the browser using standard web technology. TouchKit is an extension to give your Vaadin app the look and feel of an iOS or Android mobile app. I have used Vaadin very successfully (an amazing tool), but not yet tried TouchKit.

Comment: @BasilBourque Ive been thinking about it since I read your other answer, and truthfully vaadin is one of the best framework if not the best I've ever seen, definitely the easiest. But Vaadin TouchKit costs 600$ and I'm not sure if my app will get that money back. I just wish they could give free trial for 6 month, just to test the performance on app store.

Comment: @BasilBourque and the other thing, consuming REST in vadin is easy, but I dont think designing rest would be that easy, i could be wrong, but if I'm right, it's a big problem

Comment: I suggest contacting the [Vaadin sales team](https://vaadin.com/company#contacts) about both your questions (cost and REST).

Comment: If C# was allowed, I'd suggest [Xamarin](http://open.xamarin.com/)…

Comment: @wb9688 please post your answer, if you have time, that framework looks decent, I'll vote it up and if I cant find other answers in other languages I'll accept it soon. I don't know C# but I know it's easy to learn and if this is the only alternative then I'm going to use it